# How to ensure pen display tablet drivers are removed

Tags: windows

I have a pen display tablet, an xp pen artist 10s. https://www.xp-pen.com/goods/show/id/92.html My OS is windows 10 64 bit.

In a nutshell, it's a monitor that you can draw on with a stylus. It's not it's own computer. You have to hook it up to a computer. I'm about to get a new pen display tablet by Huion. One thing that I see over and over again is that when people have different pen displays, is that if they have multiple drivers installed, things go sideways. As in, any number of unpredictable bad things like the cursor not showing up, to the cursor only showing on the main monitor and not the pen display, etc.

When I was troubleshooting an earlier problem, I uninstalled the drivers and got the newest drivers from the xp pen website. When I installed the new drivers, it said there was an old driver still installed. **For that reason, it would seem that the uninstallation of the old drivers didn't completely uninstall.** If I'm mistaken in this assumption, then please let me know.

This may or may not be relevant, but I'm using an HDTV as a monitor as well. I would like to use the new Huion simultaneously with my HDTV.

So my question is this: How do I ensure that I've completely uninstalled all the xp pen drivers before I install this Huion, so I don't have any driver conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

you need a program that can track whole "garbage" dump of an installation, and after you initiate "standard" uninstall it will scan for leftover files that may cause an issue as one as you described in your question.

one among best is Revo - **[https://www.revouninstaller.com/](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)** 
(you can try free portable version if you want to test it in advance)

**bonus knowledge:** one of the best driver management programs with the ability to auto-download exactly right driver and keep them up to date: **https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php**
(avoid installing of **`Advanced SystemCare`**) and for smooth management of broken registry files (due to uninstallation) you can try **https://www.auslogics.com/en/software/registry-cleaner/**